# How to automatically move records between mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb

My application uses 2 mongodb collections, a big one and a small capped one, both under the same db. I want to insert documents to both collections and ensure they are written to the big collection first and the small capped collection immediately after.

Since I'm dealing with high volumes I would prefer to avoid writing synchronously to the collections.
For the same reason I'd also rather avoid polling the big collection and inserting to the small one.

Idealy I could insert records to the big collection and have them cloned automatically to the small collection after insertion.

Is there a mechanism that support this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> Idealy I could insert records to the big collection and have them cloned automatically to the small collection after insertion.

Nope, I don't think mongodb has something that will help here. You could cheat here, however. For example, you can relax write concern for the insert into capped collection (don't wait for operation result). This will speed things up a bit (at the cost of less certainty).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be certain that both records are inserted.

Comment: Well, given that mongo won't do it for you, it's you who will have to wait for the result. Scale your webworkers, I guess.

Comment: @user3780261 No transactions in MongoDB. Period. There seems to be something seriously wrong with your data model. Maybe you should take a step back and explain why you think you need this construct.

Comment: I'm using tailable cursors as a trigger for insertions to the DB. The big DB will hold all relevant data and the small capped one will be used to activate the tailable cursors. This means all records will need to be inserted into both DBs. This is model is perhaps unorthodox but it handles the volumes I need it for pretty good. My only problem is synchronizing the DBs, hence the question.